# Перестали работать ком порты на малинке

Tags: raspberry-pi

Неожиданно перестали работать ком порты на малинке, ничего нельзя подключить. Все было нормально, стабильное питание 5в 2.1 ампера, тяжелых процессов не выполняла и не перегревалась. От чего может быть и как решить проблему? При этом hdmi работает